# Wrap stray text in <p> tags

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress issue.. how do I wrap stray text in P tags?

Example:

*Before-*

```
<div class = "content">
    <img src = "hello.jpg"/>
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    Hello! this is stray text that I want to wrap with p tags
    Hello! This is another set of stray text
</div>
```

*After-*

```
<div class = "content">
    <img src = "hello.jpg"/>
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    <p>Hello! this is stray text that I want to wrap with p tags</p>
    <p>Hello! This is another set of stray text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress uses a plugin called [wpautop](http://ma.tt/scripts/autop/). This script automatically adds <p> </p> tags to new lines. In most cases, this is helpful. Sometimes, it can be a pain. In such a case you can use the [Disable Autop Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wpautop/).

You can manually control this by changing the core Wordpress scripts. I suggest using a plugin.

Comment: I didn't know about this! It seems that wpautop is now part of WP. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the stray text coming from?  Is it being entered into the WordPress WYSIWYG editor?  If so, it'll automatically wrap the text in P tags if you have empty lines before and after the text.